# When asking, how much background info is too much?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked this question ([Re-firing pointer events onto lower layer (for irregular-shaped dragging with interact.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024013/re-firing-pointer-events-onto-lower-layer-for-irregular-shaped-dragging-with-in)), which I just deleted because I decided the lack of attention probably meant it seemed way too specific/confusing.

I'm new to SO but not new to programming. I know this meta question seems to be asking for a kind of subjective answer, but I tried to follow the asking guide (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to a T:

1. **Search, and research** -- I sat on the problem for a few days, trying all sorts of workarounds for countless hours, before asking. I read docs and similar SO/Blog posts, included only the code that I thought was the best option in light of the existing literature, and included an explanation of that decision.
2. **Write a title that summarizes the specific problem** -- I wrote a title that did not deal with my particular application, but rather my specific technical stumbling block, then added a bit of application-specific detail parenthetically.
3. **Introduce the problem before you post any code** -- As concisely as possible, I described the context that gave rise to this problem, hoping that this would help readers narrow down their search space in generating answers, and that they might not waste their valuable time wondering "why are you doing this?"
4. **Help others reproduce the problem** -- I included a minimal code sample that was annotated and also a js fiddle.

and I somehow still ended up with a convoluted question that nobody touched (I think I remember that it got some votes, but broke even, meaning some people disliked it).

In fact, when I came back to the question just now to try to edit it and improve it, I found myself making the problem more accessible by actually following these guidelines **less**. I started removing all the application-specific info about the irregular/transparent images, but then I realized the code sample and js fiddle would be harder to follow, and when I thought about wasting fewer words describing my failed attempt, the question basically became a carbon-copy of existing questions about pointer events, and it began to show little research effort. Unlike some other posters asking for help formulating questions, I don't think that my only problem was being too specific--there is lots of buzz on this topic (see: http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/).

To be clear, I'm not offended that it wasn't answered--it hadn't been up for very long, it only got 16 views, and I'm by no means entitled to get help from a community of volunteers. I also don't think the question was perfect. I deleted it precisely because when I revisited it I thought it was confusing. Also, calling part of interact.js "buggy" sounds snarkier than I meant to be (thanks for the great, robust library, Taye!), I just meant that the library could not match my specific use-case here.

I'm just asking: Was I really including too much background info? Was I unknowingly falling short of the standards in other ways? Are the standards not as clear as they should be? Am I wrong to think that this is an issue at all? Any and all criticism gladly accepted.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the deleted post!

[image: Screenshot of Post]

Comment: You should post a screen shot of your deleted question. Users below 10k cannot see it otherwise.

Comment: Looks reasonable post to me... Note that JavaScript is very high traffic tag (700 non-deleted post over weekend day) - so you mostly have one chance to get people to notice/answer. One concern - usage of not very popular library - which could significantly narrow down list of people willing to answer. Also consider linking to questions you've tried (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015422/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers-divs) with one-sentence explanation why it did not work.

Comment: As long as a question doesn't receive downvotes, it probably isn't a bad question and you shouldn't delete it. The reason it didn't get much attention is that people prefer answering short question, where they can get many upvotes quickly.

Comment: I'm voting to undelete this post. Or you can undelete it yourself (unless you want to rewrite it as two questions as dan1111 suggested). Although you don't have enough rep to add a bounty now, you might later. You can also answer it yourself later if no one else does in the mean time.

Comment: As of now, It has been undeleted.

Comment: More questions should be this detailed rather than "do my homework, here is half a copy & pasted question!" I'm no javascript expert so instead have an upvote and a bounty :)

Comment: hey @Tim. this question here is **almost unbelievably too long**. All you had to say here: "Was this question _ _ _ too long?"  That's it.  Regarding the linked question {which looks interesting - but I'll never know. who could conceivably read that much?} all you had to say was "How to pass through a pointer" and include maybe 2 - perhaps 3 - lines of your code (max).   Even ***the headline of*** your question is mindbogglingly too long dude.  You need only **the first four words** of the headline - at the very most.

Comment: "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"  *summarizes*?  :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**This is not a bad question.**  You obviously put a lot of effort into it, and it explains the situation well.

However, **it does require a lot of reading to understand.**  Some people will probably be put off by the large amount of text and move on rather than answering.

One thing that I noticed is you really have two different questions here:

- How do I manually fire a mouse event?
- How do I solve the underlying problem (allowing the user to click on a lower element)?

While this isn't inherently bad (often background information about the underlying problem is useful to avoid an X-Y problem), it does contribute to the complexity of the question.

I suggest you **divide the question in two** in order to simplify it.  Ask one question about creating the mouse event and another question asking about alternative approaches.  Include only the minimum relevant information in each, but make the questions link to each other.

You could start out by only posting the mouse event question, then add the other question if you don't get a good solution.  Or, you could post both questions immediately.

Comment: I agree, the question was not a bad question. It would have seriously benefited from a bounty. However, I wish that when seeing a complex question that is clearly researched enough to answer, that users would *upvote* said question in order to actually get it more attention if they themselves are not interested in answering due to complexity or cannot answer also due to complexity. As with most problems, breaking them down to their smaller components in reproducible tests is a good way to solve those problems, so the advice of asking two questions is also sound here.

Comment: @TravisJ, a good point, agreed.

Comment: This is a great point. I think for now, since the question got reopened and bountied (thanks so much for the support everyone!), I had better not edit so drastically as to remove one of those components from the post. However, after class I can try to re-word to isolate the points, and just from all the comments here I've picked up quite a few tips for posting in the future :)

Comment: "This is not a bad question" How could you know?  Are you pretending you read it all?  Age-of-the-universe proofs come in to play here.