# Proposal to support question brevity, research effort requirements, and new user assistance

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

### TL;DR

To avoid **TL;DRs** like this one, acquaint new users to SO community expectations/rules, and reduce issues [similar to this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320773/when-asking-how-much-background-info-is-too-much), I propose a new workflow for asking and displaying questions comprised of the main points below; the changes are primarily UI changes.

1. When a user asks a question, a more granular set of required and optional fields and forms need to be filled out.
2. When the question is displayed, tabs and/or "accordion"-style ([example here](https://webdesignledger.com/best-practices-accordions-in-web-design/)) sections collapse the details, allowing mods, users, etc to only peruse details relevant to them by expanding each section.

If you need a 'visualization' of my proposal, imagine this question collapsing at each of the bold headers; I will list more 'useful' headers in the details below.

I originally wanted to add multiple disclaimers to this, but now I feel it would only add clutter and risk making the post sound more defensive/personal. The minimum, crucial point I want the internet/SO community to get out of this is that ultimately is that I do care and wish for SO to be better; this post was written with that intention/goodwill.

### Introduction

I'm not an 'new' SO user in terms of how long I've had an account, but I still don't have much experience in asking questions because posting questions on SO is intimidating to me [and seemingly others](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d). Recently when I ask a question, I try to reconcile several seemingly-conflicting considerations:

1. How do I keep my question brief and clear?
2. How do I also list the copious details and research I did without violating #1?

I feel my proposal can achieve a good balance between the considerations above as well as provide benefits to both people who ask and people who answer.

### Section A: Proposal for Asking Questions

1. When users ask a new question, they can go through the usual prompts and notices as done currently (shown a list of similar questions, etc). **Keep this, this is good.**
2. Keep the question title field
3. Remove the current text/html editor
4. Add a separate text/html editor for "Research Effort"; mark this text-box/field as required for question submission
5. Add a separate text/html editor for "Updates & Clarifications"
6. Add a separate text/html editor for "Introduction/Background/Fluff(tm)"

### Section B: Proposal for Displaying/Answering Questions

1. Once question is submitted, display each text/html editor above as a collapsible accordion section or a tab.
2. Each section/tab has a comment section and can be flagged.
3. Each section/tab has a upvote/downvote counter
4. The question itself now has a aggregated/averaged/weighted score calculated by (TBD) algorithm chosen by SO staff, instead of the current down/up vote score. This score's role/effects would be the same as the down/up vote in terms of rep, etc.

### Rationale

1. **Section B1** will help all users of all types (mods, lurkers, etc) to get to the information they need quickly in order to achieve their goals; this should minimize time spent, while maintaining brevity from that user's perspective. A lot more feedback is expressed to the OP, with only the added workload of an additional down/upvote per section.
2. **Section A4** leverages the site/UI to do the hinting to all users (especially new users) that research is required. Reduce need for comments of "what have you tried"? A4 is extensible/scalable to any section/information that SO staff see as required for a 'good' question.
3. **Section A4** may make [Help vampires](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)/trolls give up upon submitting (mission accomplished)...
4. or at least, if they continue to troll this section; then at least it is easy to point out the 'trolling'/issue because of sections B2,B3.
5. **Sections B2-B4** , help OP target issue/receive feedback while minimizing textual explanation from mods and those that answer (who have to mod/answer **many** questions). Just down/upvote the specific section to either promote good sections or dissuade weak sections.
6. For new users, an averaging of score (Section B4) can potentially reduce frustration of initial downvoting; the targeted down/upvoting helps users who care about feedback to be able to action on the weak sections. It is hard to extrapolate feedback from a single down/upvote counter
7. **Section A6**'s usefulness is controversial, which is exactly why it is in its own collapsible section. Some people might desire the information, and can see its merits. For those that don't, it is time saved to leave this section collapsed.

Comment: It's all in the help center, OP's just dont read. And we have down and close votes to lead them there.

Comment: IIRC (don't have a source atm) the team is working on improving the "Ask" page to help new users with crafting their questions. I'm pretty sure Tim Post has mentioned it a few times recently.

Comment: @Kendra https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page

Comment: @rene I was thinking more a recent comment/answer from Tim specifically mentioning it... But pretty sure they're considering ideas from that post.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm not stalking Tim so I might miss important events ;)

Comment: *Add a separate text/html editor for "Updates & Clarifications"* The edit history makes having specific "Edited to Add" type sections unnecessary.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think we know how most people feel about reading long posts; the same can be said about reading long lists of rules in an FAQ or help center. If the User Interface can gently encourage people in the right direction, without 'reading' a long list of rules, I don't see why that is a bad thing. I think its natural for people to be inclined to do things in the path of least resistance. If people can follow rules with less reading, that is a boon to them; isn't the goal just to make them follow rules? Does the method in which to do so ultimately matter?

Comment: Can you imagine that I get fed up with posts that refer to off-site rants as evidence.

Comment: @Kendra this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/kind-reminder-to-remove-noise/343725#343725 ?

Comment: @rene That's it! I was looking for it myself.

Comment: I reinstated stalking Tim Post and I have immediate success ...

Comment: I also don't think making the voting system more complicated is necessary. Even if we should allow a way for users to indicate exactly where a question has problems (there have been a few feature requests to do something similar, though not in the same way), it shouldn't change the existing voting system.

Comment: [Here is another way to phrase the 'mindset' of this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page#comment361526_326868)

Comment: @BSMP Im just wondering if we can apply the existing voting system to more parameters in the question, as opposed a single up/down vote to the question as a whole.

Comment: But how does a weighted score help more than the simple up/down we have now? Putting aside the ability to mark specific parts of the question, how does changing actual scoring help?

Comment: @BSMP It gives more opportunities for the OP to show that their intentions are indeed to ask a good question. If a good question was asked, but the evidence was lacking, then a vote to the research section, will notify the OP what should be done. Ambiguity is removed, and accountability is strengthened. If I give someone the tools to change, and they don't, then it becomes clearer what their actual intentions are. At that point we can choose to help further or ignore. If feedback is more ambiguous, it's harder to tell if the OP is lazy or actually confused about what needs to be done

Comment: To rephrase, granular feedback I feel is always beneficial to OP and other new SO users, its just a matter of how to give the feedback without while reducing the time/resources used on the "moderator/answerer" side.

Comment: I wish people would stop using that article as evidence of problems. It really is just one guy's opinion. (I'm not saying there isn't room for improvement.)

Comment: Related: [Let's improve Stack Overflow's "Ask a Question" page!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326868) [Display basic guidelines in new question window](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309235)

Comment: But none of that explains why that needs to be tied to how the *score* is tabulated. I understand you want people to give the OP more specific feedback by marking specific parts of a question. I don't understand why you want how the score is tabulated to change. You want an *aggregated/averaged/weighted score* but why? If I've marked the part(s) of a question I have a problem with, then the goal of granular feedback has already been achieved. Changing how scoring works isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This feels very much like a proposal to turn the structure of Documentation into the structure of the Q&A. One of the major downfalls of Documentation in many people's eyes is the lack of flexibility in how to format topics. Not everything fits into the same cookie-cutter format. Likewise, I feel that adding more structure, in the form of accordion menus and section headers, is only going to create more noise.

There's a huge variety of question styles, and most great questions don't need to be highly structured, and don't require a huge amount of explanation. The system we have currently works really well for high-quality content, and gives people the ability to use their own common sense in what belongs in the question. If we need to give feedback, the current comment section works fine.

We don't need to change the current layout of how questions are presented. It works fine. The most effective way we can help new-comers is to give them as many suggestions as possible, but only a human can decide the best format for their question.

Comment: I agree with letting other people give suggestions for special cases; but for common cases, wouldn't automation and structure relieve/free up moderators and SO staff to focus on the posts that have non trivial issues? Why not use structure to help maintain a minimum level of quality for the set of users that post (intentionally or not) such lower quality questions? There will always be a new user that needs faq-level guidance, couldn't that level of guidance be enforced through automation?

Comment: We can't help with users who are intentionally asking lower quality questions, but for people who are unintentionally asking low quality questions, we don't need to change the entire system, when somebody could make an edit or a comment that fixes or guides the trivial issues. Trivial issues already get dealt with by the community instead of mods.

Comment: People tend to be opinionated and occasionally unreliable at giving suggestions in a professional manner as well. Delegating common downvoting cases to the UI could help, since a computer isn't going to be snarky in its response for required information like a user. The response is more consistent and won't get less or more friendly based on human factors.

Comment: what about users who are not intentionally posting low quality questions? Wouldn't it be less risky to have an automated response than potentially have a veteran user frustratingly respond to a new user, which can then lead to a 'human' argument? We all know of many veteran users that complain about handling the same new user pitfalls over and over? Recurring events are great opportunities for automation.

Comment: I also think that the UI can handle a large amount of the guidance in asking questions. I just don't think it needs to be so drastic. We have a tour and a help center already, and a great majority of well-meaning users already use those tools in order to get familiar with how the site works. When I first joined the site, those resources had pretty much everything I needed to know. For the veteran users who are tired of typing the same comments, [there's an app for that](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Comment: Also ...OPs are good (and new users to the site PARTICULARLY good) at takinganything said against their question as rude or snarky,no matter how nice the comment is phrased. Pretty sure that if it comes from an automated system that will only reinforce the mindset that we ARE elitists ('what? Now they even AUTOMATED their silly rules and quality standards?').... Truly not sure how helpful such a proposal would be...